# Heroku Angular Deploy - Script file ... does not exist

Tags: angular, heroku

I am trying to deploy my angular 11 app into Heroku, but I get the following error:

```
    -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    
    -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
    
    -----> Node.js app detected
    
           
    
    -----> Creating runtime environment
    
           
    
           NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    
           NODE_VERBOSE=false
    
           NODE_ENV=production
    
           NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
    
           
    
    -----> Installing binaries
    
           engines.node (package.json):  14.x
    
           engines.npm (package.json):   7.x
    
           
    
           Resolving node version 14.x...
    
           Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
    
           Bootstrapping npm 7.x (replacing 6.14.13)...
    
           npm 7.x installed
    
           
    
    -----> Restoring cache
    
           Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
    
           Module installation may take longer for this build
    
           
    
    -----> Installing dependencies
    
           Installing node modules
    
           
    
           > ucvr-web@1.0.0 postinstall
    
           > ng build --prod
    
           
    
           An unhandled exception occurred: Script file playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientAPI.js does not exist.
    
           See "/tmp/ng-3ncp52/angular-errors.log" for further details.
    
           npm ERR! code 127
    
           npm ERR! path /tmp/build_b3d04774
    
           npm ERR! command failed
    
           npm ERR! command sh -c ng build --prod
    
           
    
           npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    
           npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.pLNRU/_logs/2021-07-28T23_32_54_250Z-debug.log
    
    -----> Build failed

This is the part of my angular.json with that file:

    "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/ucvr-web",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                "aot": true,
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientAPI.js",
                  "playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabAdminAPI.js"
                ]
              },
```

With localhost works perfectly, and the folder and the file is in place inside Heroku also:
[Heroku Cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5eqR.png)

I also tried with the package inside the node_modules folder, because I made some changes to the package and I want to keep them, but I get the same error.

```
npm install -S ./playfab-web-sdk
```

Finally this is my packages.json:

```json
    {
      "name": "ucvr-web",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.x",
        "npm": "7.x"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
        "@angular/animations": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "~11.0.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "playfab-web-sdk": "file:playfab-web-sdk",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.0.8",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "playfab-web-sdk": "file:playfab-web-sdk"
      }
    }
```

Any help is very appreciate, thanks!